# "Disconnect Account" button not working in Google Chrome

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, chrome

The `Disconnect Account` button governing the connection with Sales is currently not performing the disconnect when used in Google Chrome. This was tested by two different users on different machines.

[image]

---

Posting this as a [Q&A-style post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.219346397.531951925.1627434563-717092098.1544193690) since some users are bound to encounter this until Salesforce fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce functionality impacted in Chrome 92 after recent change to cross-origin iframe JavaScript dialogs.

> As of Chrome version 92, customers may experience issues when working
> across the Salesforce platform. This impact may appear with buttons
> that were previously functioning as expected, visualforce
> pages/components, or other content not performing as expected. In the
> Chrome developer console logs impacted users will see the following
> error:
>
> A different origin subframe tried to create a JavaScript dialog. This
> is no longer allowed and was blocked. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576 for more
> details.
>
> Repro
>
> 1. Launch Chrome 92 and sign into Salesforce
> 2. Go to Setup > Users > Users
> 3. Select the Action checkbox and then click Reset Password(s)
>
> Expected Result: User is presented with a confirmation dialog to reset
> the password Actual Result: In Chrome 92 there is no response or
> dialog when clicking the Reset Password(s) button
>
> Workaround
>
> 1. Impacted users can use an alternate supported browser such as Firefox or Safari
> 2. Chrome 92 users can workaround this issue by adding the following flag to your Google Chrome Shortcut:
>    --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"

Please check this Known Issue.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BRMX

Answer (score 0):

The Console of the Developer Tools inside Google Chrome tell us this:

[image]

This means that the script running inside of an iframe that contains this button is getting blocked by Chrome as described in [this article](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576). When you click this button, two alerts should be displayed, but now those alerts are blocked and the rest of the script (that would disconnect this business unit) is not executed.

To work around this, you need to disconnect in a browser different than Chrome.